# Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK - CocoaPods won't download version 7.9.1

Tags: ios, firebase, admob

I've got a problem with CocoaPods and the dependency of 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'. 
If I run

> 'pod install'

with the entry

> pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'

it doesn't download the framework.
If I change it to the following:

> pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '7.9.0'

it works. 
All our computers got the same problem.
It seems that the version '7.9.1' has a bug.

EDIT:

Here is my Podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.0'

# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!

# here we can define globals pods that are used by all targets
def sharedPods
  pod 'Mapbox-iOS-SDK'
  pod 'CorePlot'
  pod 'GoogleAnalytics'
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
  pod 'SDCAlertView'
  pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
end

target 'serverapp' do
  sharedPods
end
```

EDIT_2:
[image: pod install --verbose]

Comment: Can you try this pod for Google Moblie Ads pod 'Firebase/AdMob'.

Comment: can you share your Podfile as well?

Comment: @Daniel do `pod install --verbose` and paste the result here.

Comment: @lawicko - I added a screenshot with the output for 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'

Comment: @DanielChristoph so what are the symptoms exactly? How can you tell that "it doesn't download the framework"?

Comment: In my root directory of the project I got the folder "Pods". In it there is a folder "Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK". In this folder there is only a "Readme.txt", no framework.

Comment: try clearing out Cocoapods cache: rm -rf "${HOME}/Library/Caches/CocoaPods"
rm -rf "`pwd`/Pods/"
pod update